# UIScrollView Button Tap Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have UIButtons arranged in a horizontal UIScrollView. I have the contentView UIView that I have added to the UIScrollView and the buttons are inside that. The scrollview content width is wider than the size of the screen so some of the buttons start by not being on the screen. When I scroll over and they are dragged onto the screen, tapping on them doesn't call the function that it's supposed. On the other hand, tapping on the buttons that originally started on the screen works. Would appreciate some help in resolving the issue.

Comment: Are you using the `UIScrollView` only for the buttons? And is there any other content? If it's only for the `UIButtons`, I would use a `UICollectionView` instead of the scroll view.

Comment: i think your buttons are out of your content view , for check this add any color to your content view and different color to your scroll view and then see if your buttons are in view or not

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little working example, in case it helps:

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let button1 = UIButton()
        button1.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        button1.setTitle("Button 1", forState: .Normal)
        button1.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        self.scrollView.addSubview(button1)
        self.scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-(100)-[button1(100)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: ["button1": button1]))
        self.scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-[button1(100)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: ["button1": button1]))
        button1.addTarget(self, action: "button1", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        let button2 = UIButton()
        button2.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        button2.setTitle("Button 2", forState: .Normal)
        button2.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        self.scrollView.addSubview(button2)
        self.scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-(500)-[button2(100)]-(300)-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: ["button2": button2]))
        self.scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-[button2(100)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: ["button2": button2]))
        button2.addTarget(self, action: "button2", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    }

    func button1() {
        print("button1")
    }

    func button2() {
        print("button2")
    }
}
```